# BIG O in reference to previous time steps

Tags: algorithm

IF I have a grid NxN that requires N^2 steps and is dependent on the grid NxN at the previous time steps does the Big O remain the same?

Comment: Can you explain more? What do you mean by dependent on previous steps?

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing something that requires `NxN` steps, the time complexity *for that something* is indeed `O(N2)`, regardless of the state of the data beforehand, or whatever process led up to the start of that something.

If the thing you're doing *requires* the inclusion of the previous steps then yes, obviously, that would need to be included in the analysis as well. However, it's the *processing required* that would affect the complexity rather than the state of the data.

For example, if the `NxN` steps needed to be performed 75 times, that would still be `O(N2)` since it's a constant multiplier. But, if you had to do it `log N` times, the complexity would become `O(N2 log N)`.